# New activities with old time appears as new activities

Tags: getstream-io

I had to delete and re-add some activities.

**Details:**

`GROUP_AGGREGATED` follows `GROUP`

I deleted all `GROUP_JOIN` activities from feed `GROUP`. Then re-added all of them with some changes, but I **didn't change the time**.

GROUP_AGGREGATED had other activities too in it, and GROUP_JOIN was in between somewhere. But after re-adding, all the re-added activities appeared as the latest. `GetStream` didn't use my `time` field.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregated feeds return results only in the order that they are added, unlike in Flat feeds in which you are able to add activities which occur in the past and they will show up in chronological order.

I've made a note to add more documentation about this in the official docs!

Comment: Is there any way to make them appear chronologically?